# Unnest array defined as string within a row in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following query

```
select 123 as user_id, "[\"A\",\"B\",\"C\"]" as category
```

which generates this data:

```
user_id       category
    123  ["A","B","C"]
```

What I would like to get from this data is:

```
user_id       category
    123              A
    123              B
    123              C
```

How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below.

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
  select 123 as user_id, "[\"A\",\"B\",\"C\"]" as category
)
SELECT user_id, category 
  FROM sample_data, UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(category)) category;
```